# Differentiate when UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification is being called

Tags: ios, notifications, application-lifecycle

In my app, if UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification is dispatched I present a modal security unlock view.

Everything is working fine except UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification seems to get called whenever the iOS shows the "The App would like to use your current location" popup.

Is there a way to differentiate when UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification is being called?

I need to show the security unlock view when the app returns from the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification instead.